# fread into multiple variables

Tags: c, linux

I have the following code:

```
// fp is a FILE opened in binary mode
unsigned char bit_depth;
unsigned char color_type;
unsigned char compression_method;
unsigned char filter_method;
unsigned char interlace_method;

fread(&bit_depth, 1, 1, fp);
fread(&color_type, 1, 1, fp);
fread(&compression_method, 1, 1, fp);
fread(&filter_method, 1, 1, fp);
fread(&interlace_method, 1, 1, fp);
```

I'd like to to all `freads` in one go, perhaps using something akin to a format string (but `fscanf` is only for text files, right?).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Put all the variables into a struct, and read the struct - after all, that's what most people use

Comment: @Petesh agree, but watch out for alignment issues....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array with 5 elements and read it into the array, something like this:

```
unsigned char infos[5];
fread(infos, 1, 5, fp);
unsigned char bit_depth = infos[0];
/* etc. */
```

Or you could put it into a struct, but watch out for alignment. To remedy that you could prefix it with a `#pragma pack` directive, but that's less portable. As the elements are of the same type I recommend the array-approach.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you just want a struct.

```
typedef struct info {
    unsigned char bit_depth;
    unsigned char color_type;
    unsigned char compression_method;
    unsigned char filter_method;
    unsigned char interlace_method;
} info_t;

info_t my_info;
fread(&my_info, sizeof(info_t), 1, fp);
```

**But**, be careful about structure padding.  If the file was written with just 5 bytes, you'll want to check in your debugger and make sure that this doesn't mess up your file pointer.  Frequently, structs are aligned to 8-byte boundaries, so see what sizeof(info_t) evaluates to, and if necessary, put a pragma around the struct to affect its alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Read the data into a buffer of sufficient size-:

```
#define READ_BUF_SZ 5

unsigned char readbuf[READ_BUF_SZ];
fread(readbuf, READ_BUF_SZ, 1, fp);
```

then assign the variables from the buffer

```
bit_depth = readbuf[0];
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

********** 30 chars needed *****************
See
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread

Comment: This is not an answer. It is at best a hint. Link only answers are also discouraged.